# Unable to install component in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

[image]

I am trying to install a Joomla component on server, but I am facing a problem.
I have the following message :

```
    JFolder::create: Could not create directory Path: ./tmp
    Warning: Failed to move file!
```

Comment: It's `Joomla` and not `Zoomla`.

Comment: Zoomla, so cute ! It seems like you have a permission issue. Does the `tmp` directory exists, and if it does, what are the permissions on it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure the tmp folder has been defined correctly, then this is most likely due to permission issues.

If you go to the following:

**Joomla backend** >> **Site** (top menu) >> **System Information** >> **Directory Permissions**

If there are any directories showing as *unwritable* then you will need to change the permissions of them. All folder should be set to **755**. If you have already done this and they are still showing as *unwritable* then you will need to contact the server administrator to change the ownership for you.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. Check for a /tmp/ folder

Solution 2. The /tmp/ folder must be readable and writable

Solution 3. The path to the /tmp/ folder must be correct in Global Configuration

For doing better, you can edit the configuration.php file as bellow:

```
var $log_path = ‘/usr/home/web/web***/joomla/logs’;
var $tmp_path = ‘/usr/home/web/web***/joomla/tmp’;
```

to:

```
var $log_path = ‘./logs’;
var $tmp_path = ‘./tmp’;
```

Comment: @codingArt...the configuration.php file contains all these settings already.Any other solution please.

Comment: check for the folder permission